# Changing Font/Size/Color/Format of highlighted text in InlineCSSTextArea javafX

Tags: java, css, javafx

I would like to be able to have the user highlight the text, and then change the font or size or color or format (bold, underline, italicize) of that highlighted text.

```
boolean b = isBold();
boolean u = isUnderlined();
boolean i = isItalicized();

String colorHexValue = getColorValue();
String f = (String)getFont();
int size = getSize();
Font font = new Font(f, size);

InlineCSSTextArea newArea = new InlineCSSTextArea();
```

I am aware that I can do

```
newArea.getSelectedText();
```

in order to get the test which is highlighted. However, that returns a String. ideally, I would like to do something like this:

newArea.getSelectedText().setFont(font);

but that does not work because  the selected text is a String, not a CssInlineTextArea. How would I go about setting the selected text to the font/size/color/format that I want? I get the feeling I'll need CSS, but I'm not sure how to apply that to only the highlighted text, nor where to write the css.

Comment: So what is InlineCSSTextArea where do you have that control from?

Comment: @tomsontom,it's from RichTextFX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about `InlineCssTextArea` from RichTextFX, use the combination of `getSelection()` and `setStyle(from, to, style)`:

```
IndexRange selection = newArea.getSelection();
newArea.setStyle(selection.getStart(), selection.getEnd(), "-fx-font-family: Helvetica");
```

If you don't want to use CSS, but rather use the Java API directly to set the properties, you will have to use `StyledTextArea` directly instead of its subclass `InlineCssTextArea`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this by yourself, have a look at [TextFlow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html):

> It can be used to layout several Text nodes in a single text flow. The TextFlow uses the text and the font of each Text node inside of it plus it own width and text alignment to determine the location for each child.

Besides you can style each single `Text` `Node` differently.

If you want to use an existing API that does most of the functionality you mentionied, I would recommend a closer look at [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX).